# Incorrect SSL-configuration for BookStack

Tags: apache, subdirectory

after trying unsuccessfully to set up BookStack with nginx, I switched to Apache.

However, I have similar difficulties setting up the subfolder.

BookStack should be available at https://domain.name/bookstack.

The location of BookStack is /var/www/bookstack/... .

I have also added the domain in the .env.

I just figured out, that the configuration for HTTP works like expected.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.name
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # BookStack Configuration
    Alias "/bookstack" "/var/www/bookstack/public"

    <Directory "/var/www/bookstack/public">
        Options FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted

        RewriteEngine On
        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </Directory>


    <Directory "/var/www/bookstack">
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    # End BookStack Configuration

</VirtualHost>
```

But when I put in the config for HTTPS (I created a certificate with certbot/letsencrypt), I get the login page without styles. As I log in, it takes me to HTTP-domain with error 404 Not found.

Here's my current SSL config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domainname
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # BookStack Configuration
    Alias "/bookstack" "/var/www/bookstack/public"

    <Directory "/var/www/bookstack/public">
        Options FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted

        RewriteEngine On
        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </Directory>


    <Directory "/var/www/bookstack">
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    # End BookStack Configuration

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certificate/file
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/certificate/key/file
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I don't get the problem with this.

Comment: have youchanged the site_url to "https://" in your .env configuration file ?